# How to Stop an image from going through another image?

Tags: object, vb6, collision-detection, game-physics

I am creating a game(Bomber Man), i need my character to not go through the wall blocks which are separate images in a control array. When i use this code the player goes through the walls and goes crazy in all directions.

*NOTE:I have already found out how to do collision detection, what my main question is what to do when collision is detected?

This is the code i have so far,

```
'imgWhite is my player,imgWall is my block of wall. 
'JUMPW is my Const variable which is set to 325

Private Sub tmrBlock_Timer()

    Dim x As Integer

    For x = 0 To 72
        If imgWhite.Left < (imgWall(x).Left + imgWall(x).Width) Then
            white.dx = JUMPW
        End If

        If imgWall(x).Left < (imgWhite.Left + imgWhite.Width) Then
            white.dx = -JUMPW
        End If

        If imgWhite.Top < (imgWall(x).Top + imgWall(x).Height) Then
            white.dy = JUMPW
        End If

        If (imgWhite.Top + imgWhite.Height) > imgWall(x).Top Then
            white.dy = -JUMPW
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better approach is to check for collision in your player chatacter movement routine?
It looks like what you are doing here is if the character is in the wall, throw them back out (by JumpW). It may be better to say that the PC can only move in a direction in the first place if there is no impediment.

Also, you should probably either use `for x = imgwall.LBOUND to imgwall.UBOUND` or `for each wall in imgwall` loop, to avoid having to make code changes every time you add (or remove) a wall.

Comment: Since im doing "Bomber Man" i need to have different directions as i have an animation running for the player. Is there another way to make an obstacle solid so it cannot be passed through? @CMaster